# segmentation fault on calloc with small allocation sizes

Tags: c

I've written code to simulate an election, and this works as intended, however when I modify BALLOT_SIZE to be 7, and change the definition of `int v[BALLOT_SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}` in New_Random_Ballot(), the statement `struct Ballot * New_Ballot = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Ballot *));` gives me a segmentation fault.  It should be noted that setting BALLOT_SIZE to 6 and modifying the definition of `int v[BALLOT_SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5}` and all smaller settings of these variables (such as length 4, 3 or 2) executes correctly. I've removed the code that shuffles the array for clarity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define BALLOT_SIZE 5
#define NUM_VOTERS 50

struct Ballot {
    int votes[BALLOT_SIZE];
};

struct Ballot * New_Random_Ballot() {

    int v[BALLOT_SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4}; 
    struct Ballot * New_Ballot = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Ballot *));

    for (int j = 0; j < BALLOT_SIZE; j++) {
        New_Ballot->votes[j] = v[j];
    }
    return New_Ballot;
}

void Hold_Election(struct Ballot * Election[NUM_VOTERS]) {
    for (int i=0; i < NUM_VOTERS; i++) {
        Election[i] = New_Random_Ballot();
    }   
}

int main() {
    struct Ballot * Election[NUM_VOTERS];
    Hold_Election(Election);

    //free memory
    for (int i=0; i < NUM_VOTERS; i++) {
        free(Election[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried catching the return value of the calloc call and checking it against NULL but before it is able to check the return value, it faults (in this example, BALLOT_SIZE is 7):

```
struct Ballot * New_Random_Ballot() {

    int v[BALLOT_SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}; 
    struct Ballot * New_Ballot = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Ballot *));

    if (New_Ballot == NULL) {
        perror("could not allocate ballot\n");
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < BALLOT_SIZE; j++) {
        New_Ballot->votes[j] = v[j];
    }
    return New_Ballot;
}
```

Comment: `calloc(1, sizeof(struct Ballot *))` --> `calloc(1, sizeof(struct Ballot))` Because `sizeof(struct Ballot *)` is pointer size. not the object size.

Comment: `sizeof(struct Ballot *)` A pointer is not the object it points to!

Comment: sizeof(struct Ballot) == BALLOT_SIZE * sizeof(int), whereas sizeof(struct Ballot*) == sizeof(void*) == 4 (or 8 for 64bit apps).  The * makes a lot of difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
calloc(1, sizeof(struct Ballot *));  // Ballot* is a pointer of size 4 or 8
```

Replace with:

```
calloc(1, sizeof(struct Ballot));  // struct Ballot is a structure of some size
```

As correctly pointed out by @Olaf below, pointer sizes may depend on the CPU.  The original answer above need a bit of clarification.

The ISO standard guarantees this equality, for any data type, struct or union AnyType:

```
sizeof(AnyType*) == sizeof(void*)
```

The size of void* is defined by the CPU architeture.  On 32-bit platforms, a pointer is 4 bytes long, on 64-bit platforms, that's 8 bytes long.

On 16 bits platforms, such as the i386, pointers will generally be 16-bits long, but there are also far pointers and `sizeof(void far*)` is *usually* 32-bits (16 bits for segment, 16 bits for address).

On 8 bit platforms, such as the i8051, logic would dictate that pointers be 8 bit wide,  but that is not very useful, so pointers are usually 16-bit wide on 8 bit CPUs.  There are usually no segments associated with pointers on 8bit cpus, and it is the responsibility of the programmer to manage far memory. i.e. changing the visible extended memory page, by setting the appropriate control registers.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: "Ballot* is a pointer of size 4 or 8" - Please provide a reference to the standard guaranteeing a pointer is 4 or 8 bytes! Are the existing implementations with `1` or `2` bytes non compliant?

Comment: So I'm creating a pointer with `struct Ballot * New_Ballot` and then pointing at a region of space that is the size of a Ballot struct, instead of pointing at a space that is the same size as the pointer?

Comment: The opposite, but that's the idea.  every time you call calloc with the wrong size, then writing,  you are corrupting the heap.  Have you considered calling malloc instead?

Comment: @michi: this is indeed the case.  A very common cause for bugs.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy is there an advantage to using malloc over calloc in this case?

Comment: calloc has 2 parameters, and is specialized to allocate arrays. malloc has only one parameter.  No other advantage than a small bit of added efficiency and a slightly bigger bit of readability.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, malloc will return any memory data, and calloc will fill it with zero bit repeated to full byte size http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html " calloc() function shall allocate unused space for an array of nelem elements each of whose size in bytes is elsize. The space shall be initialized to all bits 0."

Comment: In this case, OP fills the entire array with data immediately after the call to calloc().